# PHP using Parameters in other functions

Tags: php, oop, parameters

A general question about OOP I am have this class

```
class User{

    //call DB connection
    function User($userId){

    }

    function getMenu(){
        return $userId;
    }
}
```

How would I be able to access $userId in the getMenu function by just using

```
$user = new User($userId);
echo $user->getMenu();
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By making it a [class property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

```
class User{

    //Since you're not inheriting you can also make this property private
    protected $userId; //Or private $userId;

    /* As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a 
      namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. 
      This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.*/

    //call DB connection
    public function __construct($userId){ 
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function getMenu(){
        return $this->userId;
    }
}
```

This really is fundamental to OOP, I'd recommend that you read a few tutorials just to explain how OOP works

Comment: Thank you, got it to work now All the judos to you Mark.

Comment: Plus one altough correct I wonder why you're using `protected` and not `private` ?

Comment: I use protected for most properties because it allows for extension of the class (Open/Closed principle of SOLID).... I should also have used public visibility for the methods, but it was just a quick copy/paste from the OP's question, and I forgot to add that

Comment: Thanks for spotting the constructor name as well @Daan